# Unable to set up the new Faker library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, faker

I am trying to set up the new [@faker-js/faker](https://github.com/faker-js/faker) library. So far, I did this:

```
npm i @faker-js/faker -D
```

Added `faker.d.ts` at the top level. So the tree is like this:

[image]

`faker.d.ts` contents is this:

```
// faker.d.ts
declare module '@faker-js/faker' {
  import faker from 'faker';
  export default faker;
}
```

I am trying to use the mock like this:

```
import faker from 'faker';

import { ParameterMessage } from 'packages/ts/container/Parameter';

export const Parameter: ParameterMessage = { id: faker.dataType.uuid };
```

But am keep getting an error, saying

> Cannot find module 'faker' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
>
> Unable to resolve path to module 'faker'.

I am also getting this in `faker.d.ts`

> File '/home/aironside@ant.local/Documents/microfrontends/telegram-manager/src/faker.d.ts' is not a module.

When hovering over **'faker'** in `import faker from 'faker';`

What am I missing?

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-smoke-qx63t?file=/src/App.tsx) is a reproduced sandbox

Comment: I believe `import faker from 'faker'` in your code (_not_ in the .d.ts file!) should be `import faker from '@faker-js/faker'`.

Comment: That does not work for me atleast.

Comment: I didn't find a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a sample project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/faker-js-demo-b16k2u?file=index.ts
I may link it into our README.md if needed (I'm one of the maintainers of @faker-js/faker )

Comment: Please do link it. This would've saved my butt a while back ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try to install the corresponding type declarations by running the command `npm i @types/faker`

Comment: Unfortunately, same problem as before

Comment: From which Folder did you run the npm install's? This is a mistake I do to often (install it to the wrong directory)

Comment: The top level. Same level where we can see `node_modules`, and `faker.d.ts`

Answer (score 1):

Please check this example https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-dream-5cyq7?file=/src/App.tsx, the problem with the old faker types are that some type is missing, like the animal function.

If its possible for you please use the new released v6 of the fakerjs

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me so far is to have a faker.d.ts file in the root (where package.json is). The single entry in that file is `declare module "@faker-js/faker";`